# Asyncio start a task inside another task?

Tags: task, python-asyncio, python-3.7

i'm trying to learn the usage of asyncio but i've met a roadblock.

What am i trying to do? I'm trying to create a number of `workers` that as soon as they're created they start their own `task`. So while `task3` is being created and started `task1` should already be executing its task.  I'm doing that by using a loop inside a single `coroutine`, at eache iteration the `worker` is created and starts.

The problem i'm facing: When the first worker completes its task the others just stop and don't continue.

This is my code:

```
import asyncio

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, session_name):
        self.name = session_name
        self.messagelist = ['--------1', '--------2', '--------3', '--------4']

    async def job(self):
        for i, message in enumerate(self.messagelist):
            print(f"### Worker {self.name} says {message}")
            await asyncio.sleep(20)

class Testmanager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.workers_name = ['test0', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']

    async def create_and_start_workers(self, loop):
        for i, name in enumerate(self.workers_name):
            worker = Worker(name)
            print(f"# Created worker {worker.name}")
            loop.create_task(worker.job())
            print(f"## Started worker {worker.name}")
            await asyncio.sleep(10)

    def start(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.create_and_start_workers(loop))
        loop.close()

manager = Testmanager()
manager.start()
```

When run initially it works as expected, but after a while i get a lot of:

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<Worker.job() done, defined at PATH_REDACTED> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000026AF6315438>()]>>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem is you just create the task but you don't await them. See how you await the `asyncio.sleep`? You need to await for `Worker.job` likewise. You can clearly see that after creating the fourth test worker, it waits for 10 seconds and the program stops

Comment: If i await the loop.create_task(worker.job()) the for loop waits for the first worker in order to finish the current iteration.

I would like to iterate trough the for loop normally but start the worker's job as soon it is created

EDIT: i found that by using `loop.run_until_complete()` the loop runs only until the tasks of the function i passed are not completed. Once those are completed it ignores the added tasks from the for loop and it stops.
By using `loop.run_forever()` on the other hand i don't know how to stop the loop when i'm sure all the added tasks are completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am i doing wrong?

You are never awaiting the tasks you create to run in parallel. For example:

```py
    async def create_and_start_workers(self, loop):
        tasks = []
        for i, name in enumerate(self.workers_name):
            worker = Worker(name)
            print(f"# Created worker {worker.name}")
            tasks.append(loop.create_task(worker.job()))
            print(f"## Started worker {worker.name}")
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: Thanks, i though by doing that way it would wait for the loop to complete and then start the tasks. Thanks a lot for you help.